# Prepraing lzo or lz4 files for Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, lz4, lzo, hadoop-lzo

I'm trying to choose the right format for file exchange with my spark application. I use `Spark 2.4.7` + `Haddop 2.10` on Kubernetess.
My app downloads CSV file from S3 and process it. The file is provided by a 3rd party company.

I was thinking about asking them to use `lz4`, `lzo` or other splittable compression. However, what I can see the command line tools file format is not compatible with Hadoop `lz4` or `lzo` codecs (I tried `lzop` and `lz4` cli)

Do you know any CLI tools which allow preparing lz4 or lzo compressed files in formats which Hadoop codecs will understand?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No. Unfortunately, those formats are not standardized. So compression is the same, but for example frames format is different.
So I assume its useful to use them, use them inside of the platform, but not to integrate with the outside world.